# Proper way to export Android Studio NDK library for import into another Project

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

What is the proper way to export Android Studio NDK library for import into another Project as .so or .a while taking into account platform architectures?

I created an NDK project and added some cpp code and built the app.

If I inspect the build directory I see:

*app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/[arch]/libnative-lib.so*.

Are these the right .so files I need to export?

What is the procedure to import the .so, without source files, on the destination project?

Do I need to create a lib folder under app/libs? What is recommended?

How do I deal with the numerous architectures?